# using wordpress SMOF frameworks options safely

Tags: wordpress

Could you please tell how to use SMOF to avoid security issues with option?

https://github.com/syamilmj/Options-Framework

http://aquagraphite.com/2011/11/smof-documentation/

For example, in code of SMOF I see that options are not escaped before output to hmtl. What to do with this? Change SMOF to escape before output of options in html?
Does SMOF care about validation and sanitizing of options when it stores it?
It's rather strange that I couldn't find much info how to use SMOF safely.

Comment: You'll have a hard time finding someone blowing the whistle on [the secret masters of fandom](http://www.smof.com/)!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: That was sarcasm for "please explain what _SMOF_ is". You've added a link so I think you got it :)

Comment: The question wasn't what SMOF is.) The question is about using options safely.

Comment: I know, but initially you didn't mention what the acronym SMOF stands for, but that information is vital for the question!